# GitLabCI - Unity - Local runner - Error updating the git index in git-lfs - File is outside repository

Tags: git, shell, unity-game-engine, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying out GitLab-CI for a unity build. I have installed the runner on my local-machine. In the Checking out ref step, runner throws the following error.

Error updating the Git index:

```
fatal: '../../../../../Builds/ZviHwiHB/0/Jeevan/testprojectjeevan/ProjectSettings/b****.config' is outside repository at '/Users/jeevanmb/Builds/ZviHwiHB/0/Jeevan/testprojectjeevan'
Errors logged to '/Users/jeevanmb/builds/ZviHwiHB/0/Jeevan/testprojectjeevan/.git/lfs/logs/20230821T150256.307089.log'.
```

I'm not understanding why is it trying to fetch the file from 5 parents back.

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml.

```
stages:
  - build
  - upload

variables:
  BUILD_PATH: ~/gitlab/Builds
  BUILD_TARGET: Android

build-debug:
  stage: build
  script:
    - chmod +x ./ci/build.sh && ./ci/build.sh
  variables:
    BUILD_APP_BUNDLE: "false"
    GIT_DEPTH: 20
    BuildOptions: Development,AllowDebugging
    DEBUG_BUILD: "true"
  tags:
    - unity
  rules:
    - if: $ALLOW_BUILD == "true"
```

and this is my build.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

env

# executed from parent folder
./ci/slack_message.sh "Starting build $BUILD_NAME"

mkdir -p $BUILD_PATH
echo "Building at $BUILD_PATH"

/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.16f1/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity \
  -projectPath $CI_PROJECT_DIR \
  -quit \
  -batchmode \
  -nographics \
  -buildTarget $BUILD_TARGET \
  -customBuildTarget $BUILD_TARGET \
  -customBuildName $BUILD_NAME \
  -customBuildPath $BUILD_PATH/$BUILD_NAME \
  -executeMethod CustomBuilder.BuildCmdLine \
  -logFile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/logs

UNITY_EXIT_CODE=$?

if [ $UNITY_EXIT_CODE -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Run succeeded, no failures occurred";
elif [ $UNITY_EXIT_CODE -eq 2 ]; then
  echo "Run succeeded, some tests failed";
elif [ $UNITY_EXIT_CODE -eq 3 ]; then
  echo "Run failure (other failure)";
  exit 1
else
  echo "Unexpected exit code $UNITY_EXIT_CODE";
  exit 1
fi
```